# Objective C - Use Variable as selector

Tags: objective-c, variables, selector

I just wanted to ask how it is possible to use a variable as selector.
My code looks like this:

```
NSString *stunde = [lesson objectForKey:@"stunde"]; // value is t1s1, then t1s2 then t1s3 etc.
t1s1.text=subject;
```

this works without a problem. But as I have to loop through 40 labels, it would be awesome to do it like this:

```
NSString *stunde = [lesson objectForKey:@"stunde"];
        **stunde**.text=subject;
```

how i can i talk with the label dynamically by using the value which i got form the json string in a for loop.

Result should look like this:

```
NSString *stunde = [lesson objectForKey:@"stunde"];
        t1s1.text=@"English";

NSString *stunde = [lesson objectForKey:@"stunde"];
        t1s2.text=@"German"; 

NSString *stunde = [lesson objectForKey:@"stunde"];
        t1s3.text=@"Business Studies";
```

etc.....

I hope you can help me and know what I mean

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I just got in working (hard coded) like this:

```
labels[0] = t1s1;
    labels[1] = t1s2;
    labels[2] = t1s3;
    for (NSDictionary *lessons in list)
    {
        int TotalLessons = [list count];

        NSString *fach = [lessons objectForKey:@"fach"];
        UILabel *stunde = [lessons objectForKey:@"stunde"];
        //labels[counter]=stunde;

        labels[counter].text=fach;


        counter=counter+1;
        if(counter>=TotalLessons){
            break;
        }



    }
```

but as there will be 40-50 labels I would like to add the label_names dynamically to the array:
like this:

```
UILabel *stunde = [lessons objectForKey:@"stunde"];
labels[counter]=stunde;
```

the value "stunde" will be defined as UILabel and then added to the array. But why is the app crashing? whats wrong? :(

thanks

Comment: What is this with beginners feelings this urge to toy with `eval`-esque things? Anyway, the answer is arrays (or any other collection) - a billion times faster, more secure and saner. My ObjC-fu is literally zero, so just a snarky comment instead of an answer ;)

Comment: unfortunately i'm a bloody beginner :( could you show me an example how to solve this? thx

Answer (score 1):

You should first initialize a dictionary like this:

```
NSDictionary *Labels = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
    LabelObject1, @"LabelObjectName1",
    LabelObject2, @"LabelObjectName2",
    LabelObject3, @"LabelObjectName3",
    ...
    LabelObjectN, @"LabelObjectNameN",
    nil];
```

then you can access each label in the following way:

```
NSString *stunde = [lesson objectForKey:@"stunde"];
((UILabel *)[Labels objectForKey:stunde]).text = @"Some text";
```

Comment: i get an error message :( "request for member 'text' in something not a structure or union

Comment: Have you declared each `LabelObjectX` as `UILabel *LabelObjectX` ?

Comment: @Christopher: the problem is that `objectForKey:` returns an `id`.  This means that it is taking the `.text` to mean a C struct member, not a property accessor.  The problem should go away if you do this: `[[Labels objectForKey:@"stunde"] setText: @"Some text"];`

Comment: ah, you're right. I used here dot syntax, which requires type to be known at compile time. JeremyP's variant is ok. I've also updated my answer.

Comment: hi guys, i just updated my questions. could you just have a quick look on it, please

Comment: @Christopher - don't append a second question. If this answer was correct +1 it, accept it and make a new question for your other problem.